# Transfer of electrons and static electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

From what I currently understand about static electricity, electrons "jump" from one object to another, which object loses electrons depends on where it falls on the Triboelectric series.

For example if I were to walk across some carpet and electrons on my shoes were to transfer onto the carpet, I am now positively charged and the carpet has an excess of electrons. Because I am now positively charged when I touch something such as a door knob, the electrons will be attracted to my excess of protons causing the ESD.

My question is, what happens to the excess of electrons that were on the carpet, and is the door knob now positively charged since it lost some electrons that transferred onto my body?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your body and your door knob both ate positively charged. Only some of your positive charge is transferred to door.Difference is that your body is now less positive.
Negative charge on carpet is as it was earlier.

Comment: When you say "Only some of your positive charge is transferred to door", is that so everything equals out again? What I find hard to understand is the state of the door knob after the transfer, how does it get back the lost electrons from the ESD?

Comment: now the door is partially positive charged. With long time it will get its charge back, from atmosphere and carpet lose its charge to atmosphere eventually. Or if some one else touch door knob positive charge is further reduced and transferred.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading answer.  Electrons move from the door leaving it positively charged.